# How do I transfer operating system Mac OS Yosemite to external hard drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-yosemite

I want to take the operating system from internal drive and copy it
to an external drive that I can boot into. I am doing this so I can
use disc utility from external system and run disc utilities on internal
drive, then replace the internal hard drive if necessary and restore the
current operating.

I assume it involves making a disc image of the internal drive and transfering it to the external drive.

System is Mac OS Yosemite.

Comment: Why not use the Recovery Partition? (Apple Key + R) - and then you can run the Disk Utility from the Recovery partition

Comment: It's unclear why you are trying to move the entire drive contents to the external drive. Are you trying to backup the drive before working on it? There are bootable OSes that fit on thumbdrives that have disk utilities and you wouldn't have to try to image the internal drive to an external drive and then boot to it.

Comment: I do want to back up the hard drive so I can replace the internal hard drive

Comment: Not adding this as an answer, otherwise it just becomes a software request, but [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) is one of the go-to utilities to do this. It will also copy the Recovery Partition to your external drive & be 100% bootable.